# Python Selenium. Проблема

Tags: python, selenium

Всем доброго времени суток. Пишу бота для Инстаграмма, который будет комментить выбранный пост, но в момент поста появляется ошибка

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
> (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)

Ну а вот собственно код
Ошибка появляется когда должен начаться цикл
Ypffh это таг где место под комментарий в посте

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from auth_data import username, password
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from target_coms import tar_com

print('Preparing! Let me know some things, enter it below this messege')
sleep(3)
tar_url = input('Enter Target url: ')
print('Thx, hope url doesnt wrong, we start soon')
sleep(3)


def auth():
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('Chrome/chromedriver.exe')
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get('https://instagram.com')

    username_input = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username_input.clear()
    username_input.send_keys(username)

    sleep(2)

    password_input = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_input.clear()
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    sleep(2)

    login_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    login_link.click()
    sleep(5)
    browser.get(tar_url)
    sleep(5)
    for i in range(1, 5):
        comments_put = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')
        comments_put.click()
        comments_put.send_keys(tar_com + str(i))
        comments_put.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(2)
    sleep(10)
    browser.close()


auth()
```

Answer (score 0):

Это частая ошибка, когда вы пытаетесь работать с интерактивными элементами (особенно, когда это генерируемые на лету элементы). Суть ситуации в следующем: когда элемент создается с помощью JS, сперва он просто создается в документе, а потом приаттачевается в DOM к определенному узлу. Ошибка, которую вы получаете, указывает на то, что вы обратились к элементу в момент, когда операции с ним еще не были завершены и он не готов к работе - не приаттачен к узлу дерева DOM.

Обойти этот момент можно несколькими способами:

1. установив харкодный `time.sleep` на 0,5-3 секунды перед обращением к элементу. Обычно этого достаточно.
2. Использовать [встроенные механизмы ожидания](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) (WebDriverWait и implicitly_wait; последний используется в вашем случае). Однако, они меня в моих проектах почему-то периодически подводят, поэтому я для себя решил использовать следующий способ.
3. Собственные ожидающие функции. Их структура достаточно простая. Нужно всего лишь в цикле проверять доступность элемента. В случае ошибки - продолжать ожидание, в случае успеха - выходить из цикла. Одним из достоинств этого метода может служить возможность добавления в такую функцию дополнительных операций (например промежуточного логирования и проверок) в процессе ожидания.

   Примерный вариант реализации:

```py
def get_element_when_ready(selector):
    while True:
        try:
            element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
        except:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return element
        
elem = get_element_when_ready('.password')
```

Comment: Добавление задержки не помогло высвечивает тоже самое.
Функцию которую вы написали в пункте 3. Использовать перед циклом в основном коде или где будет лучше ?

Comment: Ее нужно использовать вместо стандартного метода получения элемента ровно в том месте, где получаете ошибку. Если вы получаете ошибку в первой строке цикла `comments_put = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Ypffh')`, то нужно ее заменит на `comments_put = get_element_when_ready('.Ypffh')`. Обратите внимание, что я использую для доступа не имена классов, в css-селекторы. Для этого в строке определения пометил класс предстоящей точкой

Comment: get_element_when_ready нет такого

Comment: Так называется функция, которую я написал в ответе. Замените на ваше название